# error: jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I am getting error while trying to build android ndk project:

```
error: jni.h: No such file or directory
```

But: `locate jni.h` command  show me:

```
locate jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/jni.h
```

What is wrong in my actions?

EDIT:

If I hardcode it in the source code it work but I have a lot of files that are using this header. What I need to do that all my files can see /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/jni.h
?

Comment: Try hardcoding the path. Just because the file exists doesnt mean the compiler can see it.

Comment: @Jug6ernaut NO, DO NOT HARD CODE THAT PATH as that is an include for the host.  Building an android app means cross compiling, so the jni.h in the android ndk headers is required.

Comment: @drifter - it's impossible to tell what is wrong with your actions since you haven't told us what actions you are taking to build your project.  Unless you have unusual requirements, start by building the hellojni example in the ndk distribution to verify a working installation, and then set up your own project the same way.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, i said "try" as in for testing purposes, not an ultimate solution(why i said it in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the installation location of your NDK in `PATH` in your `rc` file, let's say `~/.bashrc`:

```
NDK=/path/to/your/ndk/location    
export PATH=$PATH:$NDK
```

Source the `rc` file by running `source ~/.bashrc`.

Now when you run `ndk-build`, it will setup the whole build environment for you by running `make` command against a bunch of `make` files under `$NDK/build/core`, it will setup correct **header file search path** for your project depending on the `android:targetSdkVersion` setting in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The `jni.h` needed by your NDK project is located under `$NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include`.

Android NDK projects will not use any JNI header files under your JDK installation, files under `/usr/lib/jvm/....` will never be touched.

Comment: Hopefully that path was given for information purposes only as it assumes a particular platform version and target architecture.  In a properly configured project, one should let the path be supplied by the build system.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `$NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include` is just an example, it is determined by the build system(ndk-build).